# Rails + Devise: Halt login process if constraints not met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I am trying to restrict the login process, so that when a user logs in with a wrong IP address, the session is not created and I will show af flash explaining what happened.

Most of my logic works, but the issue is, that the session is created anyway, if the condition end in the else clause.

```
class Employees::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :validate_ip, only: [:create]

  layout 'devise'


  def validate_ip
     # Pseudo code
     if ENV['ip] == remote_ip
         create
     else
         flash[:alert] = "Ip does not match"
     end

  end

end
```

I have no worked a lot of with devise, so I don't know the correct way of doing it.

But this code (and previous attempts) work fine, except for the fact that no matter what, the session continues to get created.

Comment: I've never heard of an online system that *requires* login from a specific IP address! At that point, you may as well run it on an internal network, no?

Comment: Oh maybe I explained it badly. But what I need to know is just if it is possible to halt the create session process? If the condition is not fulfilled, then don't login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a redirect or a render in your `validate_ip` filter: if you simply return from the filter, `devise` will continue to execute normally, so the user will be logged in.

Something like `redirect_to root_url, alert: "Ip does not match"` on your `else` branch should work.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Eugen. I just tried, that exact command, but it just goes to the "dashboard", logged in, and displays that flash. 

This seems to indicate that there is something wrong with the setup?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you declare the filter with `prepend_before_action :validate_ip` instead of `before_action`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write. That solved the issue, thank you Eugen!